# 301 Redirect or bind more domain names in IIS7 WIN2008

Tags: iis-7, redirect, http-status-code-301

For example, I have domain name abc.com

I want both abc.com and www.abc.com can access the same website.

I know two ways to do that, one is add one more site and setup 301 permanent redirect to the 'www' webiste.

Another way I know is binding one more domain  on the domain name without 'www'

Which way is better? If for the SEO purpose, which is better?

The reason I hate to do with the first one is I have to create two site, it looks bad in IIS7 website tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you should place www.abc.com to your abc.com's web binding settings rather than creating a new site then do a permanent redirect to your main site.

Make sure that www.abc.com and abc.com's domain settings be pointing to the same IP server, and you'll be ok with it.

Hope this helps!